# http result in contructor not available in ngoninit

Tags: jquery, angular

Using angular2 with jquery, I am getting a list from API(have result), but it does not bind into jquery:

```
list: Array<any> = [];
constructor(public http: Http){
   // I can get result from api
   this.list = http.get(...) ...

   // If I just pass value to list, it works
   //this.list = [{"test":"hello"}];
}
ngOnInit() {
    // using Jquery function, but the this.list is empty?
    (<JQueryCustom>$("#textarea")).makeInput({
        source: this.list, 
        showAtCaret: true
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's expected.

You need to move your code to

```
http.get(...).subscribe(response => {
  // code that uses `response` goes here
});
```

`ngOnInit()` is executed directly after the constructor is called.
The call to the server takes a looong time related to how fast execution within the browser is. The call to the server is async and at first only scheduled into the event queue for later execution. `ngOnInit` is sync and processed within the same "event".

When the response from the server arrives the callback passed to `subscribe(...)` is called and this is when the response is available.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
constructor(public http: Http){

   http.get(url).subscribe(response => this.list = response)
}
```

Now the list will get the data from the api,  list = http... will not work.
Also I use response but you can use any other variable name.

The constructor is the first to load but don't use it to heavy lift like http requests do that in the ngInit hook.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html